# How to connect TFS 2012 with a remote database using sql server authentication?

Tags: team-foundation-server

I am trying to use a remote dabase for TFS 2012 using SQL Server authentication.
I can not use Windows authentication because my database is in a different domain.

Can anyone tell me, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done. Windows authentication is required. See this msdn topic.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd631889(v=vs.110).aspx

You should consider using SQL Express, which comes with the tfs 2012 basic install. This way you can have a local instance of SQL Server.